# Как использовать общую память для двух процессов С линукс

Tags: c++, linux, c, ipc

Нужно сделать общим для нескольких процессов массив структур. Решил сделать так: один из процессов выделяет общий блок памяти с помощью `shmget`, другие процессы подгружают к себе указатель на этот блок памяти. Когда нужно записать значение в поле элемента массива, делаю так: `((PRUNNING_CONTEXT)(shm + (sizeof(RUNNING_CONTEXT) * i)))->name` , т.е. смещаю указатель в общей области на количество элементов, преобразую к указателю на элемент массива, и обращаюсь к полю. По неизвестной причине при попытке записи/чтения через `contextByNum(num)->field` получаю `segmentation fault(core dumped)`.

В `initContexts` выделяется блок памяти, в него копируется пустой массив с помощью `memcpy`, затем с помощью `commonSetupContext` выполняется начальная инициализация. В `main` вызывается `initContexts`, затем выводятся все имена контекстов. Падает в `commonSetupContext` при попытке `strcpy(pContext->name, getProcessName(num))`. Для интереса пробовал убрать strcpy - падает при обращении к любому полю, как для записи так и для чтения.

```
//runningContext.h
typedef struct _runningContext {
    int num;
    int numNextActiveContext;
    int active;
    int pid;
    int ppid;
    int pgid;
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    int replaceAmount;
    int replaceNums[REPLACE_NUMS_SIZE];
    int killId;
    int killSig;
    int killUsr;
    int usrRec;
    int usr1Rec;
    int usr2Rec;
    int currRecAmount;
    int needRecAmount;
} RUNNING_CONTEXT, *PRUNNING_CONTEXT;

extern RUNNING_CONTEXT contexts[PROCESSES_AMOUNT];
extern int shmKey;
extern int shmId;
extern char* shm;

//runningContext.c
void initContexts() {
    shmId = shmget(shmKey, sizeof(contexts), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmId < 0) {
        logerror("Fatal! Can't shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    shm = shmat(shmId, NULL, 0);
    if(shm == (char*)-1) {
        logerror("Fatal! Can't shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(shm, contexts, sizeof(contexts));
    for(int i = 0; i<PROCESSES_AMOUNT; ++i) {
        commonSetupContext(contextByNum(i + 1), i + 1);
    }
}


void loadContexts() {
    shmId = shmget(shmKey, sizeof(contexts), 0666);
    if(shmId < 0) {
        logerror("Fatal! Can't shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    shm = shmat(shmId, NULL, 0);
    if(shm == (char*)-1) {
        logerror("Fatal! Can't shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void commonSetupContext(PRUNNING_CONTEXT pContext, int num) {
    strcpy(pContext->name, getProcessName(num));
    pContext->num = num;
    logerror("debug");
    pContext->pid = PROCESS_ID_NOT_SET;
    pContext->replaceAmount = 0;
    pContext->usrRec = 0;
    pContext->usr2Rec = 0;
}

PRUNNING_CONTEXT contextByNum(int num) {
    if(isNumExists(num) == FALSE) {
        logerror("Num not exists, custom error");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<PROCESSES_AMOUNT; ++i) {
        if(((PRUNNING_CONTEXT)(shm + (sizeof(RUNNING_CONTEXT) * i)))->num == num) {
            return (PRUNNING_CONTEXT)(shm + (sizeof(RUNNING_CONTEXT) * i));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

//main
initContexts();
for(int i = 0; i<PROCESSES_AMOUNT; ++i) {
    logerror("%d. %d", contextByNum(i + 1)->name);
}
```

Comment: И кстати, еще не понятна строчка `memcpy(shm, contexts, sizeof(contexts));` что находится в contexts на момент запуска ? Что то мне подсказывает, что там просто нули (если повезет) и можно было бы его вообще не объявлять, а сделать memset(shm,0,...)

Comment: @Mike Мне казалось, что так надёжнее для преобразования указателей) Уже убрал.

Comment: Еще дописал в ответ как я это вижу, думаю это немного упростит код :) По сути вы всегда можете использовать указатель на структуру, с квадратными скобками, как массив, главное конечно контролировать номер элемента, что бы не вылезти за предел памяти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вызове `commonSetupContext()` первым параметром идет вызов `contextByNum()`, который ищет контекст по номеру ... Но судя по содержимому `commonSetupContext` этот самый номер будет установлен им. Следовательно в момент первого вызова `contextByNum` номера еще нет в структуре и эта функция возвращает NULL ...

Вообще я бы делал примерно так:

```
RUNNING_CONTEXT *contexts;
...
shmId = shmget(shmKey, sizeof(RUNNING_CONTEXT)*PROCESSES_AMOUNT, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
...
contexts=(RUNNING_CONTEXT *)shm;

// Вместо (PRUNNING_CONTEXT)(shm + (sizeof(RUNNING_CONTEXT) * i)))->num
contexts[i]->num
```

И если эти самые num не случайны, а как в вашем примере идут подряд, то их поиск так же не нужен, ибо `&contexts[num-1]` уже готовый адрес нужной структуры.